# X-RAY production from Coolidge Tube

Tags: x-rays

In a Coolidge tube, electrons are ejected with a Kinetic Energy. They strike the metal target and during collisions lose some part of the KE which gets emitted in the from of electromagnetic waves(photons of varying energy). Not that it matters, but just for curiosity, Where do the electrons go from there? I can not find the answer to this in any explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The electrons are probably taken by the anode to complete the electron current flow!